# Set a variable to name my new table created with PHP

Tags: php, database, variables, insert

I want to create a table via PHP, with a variable where i define the name of the table.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $variable (annual_target,maleLB,maleSB,famaleLB,famaleSB,total,accomplishment,accomp) VALUES ('$annual_target', '$maleLB', '$maleSB', '$famaleLB', '$famaleSB', '$total', '$accomplishment', '$accomp');";
```

Comment: This is an insert query. Before inserting, check if the table exists otherwise create one. You can use SQL's CREATE TABLE

Comment: Great. What's your question?

Comment: $tod = date("d/m/Y");
$str2 = $tablen;
$today = $str2.$tod;



$sql = "CREATE TABLE `{$today}` (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    annual_target VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    maleLB VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    maleSB VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    famaleLB VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    famaleSB VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    total VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    accomplishment1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    accomp VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)"; then i what to insert value to new table using variable,

Comment: do `SHOW CREATE` query on a table that has the schema you want and then replace the table name.  Make sure `$variable` is not supplied by an end user, for security reasons.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html

Comment: i create table using button and i wan't to automatically set the $variable name to insert the value .(sorry for may bad english)

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE table_name (
    column1 datatype,
    column2 datatype,
    column3 datatype,
   ....
);
And here datatype can be int or other and other size can also be specified with datatype(size).